# What fonts does Apple utilize in the Settings app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to know what text/font settings Apple uses to create the header text used in the iPhone. As an example, if you go to Settings -> Wi-Fi there will be header text which says "Choose a Network..."

How do I get my text to look like this and/or is there documentation anywhere on the text settings apple uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the standard system fonts? From [UIFont class](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference:

> #### Creating System Fonts
>
> [`+ systemFontOfSize:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/systemFontOfSize%3a)
>   [`+ boldSystemFontOfSize:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/boldSystemFontOfSize%3a)
>   [`+ italicSystemFontOfSize:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/italicSystemFontOfSize%3a)

A little try with colors and shadow:

```
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]];
[label setTextColor:
    [UIColor colorWithRed:0.223
                    green:0.266
                     blue:0.349
                    alpha:1.0]];
[label setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0,1.0)];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to achieve similar look as they use, try something like this

```
UILabel *shadowedText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 6, 250, 20)];
[shadowedText setText:@"Hello World"];
[shadowedText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[shadowedText setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.298 green:0.337 blue:0.424 alpha:1]];
[shadowedText setShadowColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
[shadowedText setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0)];
[shadowedText setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
[shadowedText sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

To know all system font available, go to 
www.iosfonts.com (very useful!)